# Is there a way to select an array using operators and paint the element in the desired color?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have component Area (lines in the chart):

```
<Area
          type="monotone"
          strokeWidth={2}
          dataKey="data"
          stroke="#3B82F6" // here is what I want to do
          fillOpacity={1}
          fill="url(#colordata)"
        />
```

And I map data into this component:

```
const data = [
  {
    name: "Jan",
    data: 3490,
    data2: 4300,
    data3: 2100,
  },
  {
    name: "Feb",
    data: 2390,
    data2: 3800,
    data3: 2500,
  },
  {
    name: "Mar",
    data: 1890,
    data2: 3000,
    data3: 2181,
  },...
```

I thought you could do something like this:

```
{data.map((data, index) => (
<Area
...
stroke={data[1] && "#someColor" & data[2] && "#someColor" ... 

OR

stroke={data[1] && "#someColor" : data[2] && "#someColor" ... 


...
```

Is there any way to select index and color in my case? Code above isn't working.

I know that I can use: data[index] === 1 ? "#3B82F6" : "#otherColor" OR data[0] && "#color"

Is there any way to execute the condition inside the stroke? I get only one condition, and I need 2-3-4-5 conditions to be fulfilled. That is, the colors should be different, not the same.

I need 2-3 lines with different colors. Can I get it inside "stroke"?

Comment: Your `data` is not valid JavaScript.

Comment: Have corrected.

Comment: It's still not clear what you're trying to do. It would be helpful to see sample data with the expected result.

Comment: @Unmitigated I have edited the description to make it more detailed and clear.